# Filter data after groupby by total count

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter data from the total count after groupby.

data is like that :

```
           Rating      Num  Year
0               6  1001508  2009
1               6  1001508  2009
2               6  1001508  2009
3               7  0100802  1990
4               7  0100802  1990
```

i groupby data and count it.

```
data.groupby(['Year'])["Rating"].count()
```

and output is :

```
2017    225
2018    215
2019    397
2020     82
2021     39
```

However, couldn't filter after that. I want to more than 50 for example.

tried

```
data[data.groupby(['Year'])["Rating"].count()<10]
```

and some variations but couldn't work it out. Lastly, i'm using mean of of these years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case change to `transform`

```
out = data[data.groupby(['Year'])["Rating"].transform('count')<10]
```

Comment: thank you. it is very basic :) actually, i used before and didn't work it out but now works fine.